# ctypes: pass numpy to c++ dll

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ctypes

I am using C++ to implement a dll, and python to use it. When I pass a numpy to dll, a bug is reported

My C++ code is:

```
    __declspec(dllexport) void image(float * img, int m, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", img[i]);
        }
    }
```

In the above code, I just pass a numpy, and print it.

Then, my python code to use this dll is:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./bin/Release/dllAPI.dll")

img = np.random.random(size=[3, 3])*10
img = img.astype(np.float)
img_p = img.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
lib.image.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
lib.image.restype = None
print('c++ result is: ')
lib.image(img_p, 3, 3)
print('\n original data is:')
print(img)
```

The printed information is:

```
c++ result is: 
-536870912 -1073741824 0 1610612736 -1073741824 1073741824 1610612736 536870912 -2147483648 
 original data is:
[[7.76128455 3.16101652 7.44757958]
 [2.32058998 9.96955139 3.26344099]
 [9.42976627 1.34360611 8.4006054 ]]
```

My C++ code print a random number, and it looks like the memory is leakage.

My environment is:

```
win 10
vs 2015 x64
python 3.7
ctypes 1.1.0
```

How can I pass a numpy to C++ by `ctypes`? Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

----------------- update ----------------------

The C++ code has a bug for `printf`, and I updated the C++ code as:

```
    __declspec(dllexport) void image(float * img, int m, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
        {
            printf("%f ", img[i]);
        }
    }
```

However, the printed information is still incorrect:

```
c++ result is: 
12425670907412733350375273403699429376.000000 2.468873 0.000000 2.502769 4435260031901892608.000000 2.458449 -0.000000 2.416936 -4312230798506823897841664.000000 
 original data is:
[[7.50196262 8.08859399 7.33518741]
 [6.67098506 0.04736352 9.5017838 ]
 [3.47544102 9.09726041 0.48091646]]
```

Comment: You need `%f` for floating point print, otherwise the memory will be interpreted as `int` without casting. (Test shows that `double a = 2.5` prints as `-1439846888`). The compiler should have warned you about this. Try casting to `int` if you want to round.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have correct my c++ code. And the printed information is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of digging I found that apparently `numpy.float`, was actually equivalent to `ctypes.c_double`(?), and you should do `img.astype(ctypes.c_float)`, so that the pointer points to the valid result. I don't know why `np.float` would be a 64 bit float, but from my debugging that's what I saw. If you want to reproduce this try printing `img_p[0]` in python to see.

Note: Using the specific cast may be best practice in this case, because different dtypes may be implementation defined, leading to this exact error (even though both are `float`)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the `numpy.float` make this bug. I replace `img = img.astype(ctypes.c_float)` with `img = img.astype(np.float32)`, and the result is correct. In addition, how can we debug the dll? My process is: run the python code with debug, and set the break point before `lib.image(img_p, 3, 3)`; then, I attach the vs to the pycharm64.exe process. But, I find I still can not enter the C++ code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @QiangZhang You can try to debug it from a `c++` program using it. You can also try to put `asm(".byte 0xcc");` at the start of the function. That should give control over to the debugger you are using (It is the `int3`(breakpoint) instruction on x86-64/x86 if I remember correctly). To be honest I never used a debugger on python code before, especially with `ctypes`. Note: I think `trap`, crashes the program if no debugger is attached if I remember correctly (or on linux it did)